# JavaScript - Variable undefined within promise chain

Tags: javascript, promise, scope, addeventlistener

In the following event listener, event variable is undefined in the ***then*** call.   But if the event variable is reassigned to variable with different name it works. What is the difference ?

```
document.addEventListener(EVENT_REVIEWED, function() {

  var someCondition = self.id == model.id;    
  var event = event;  // This does not work. 
  var _event = event; // This works 

  Promise.resolve().then(function() {
    return self.checkToLoad();
  }).then(function(){     
    self.postCall = null;

    if (someCondition ) {     
      //  Gives an error that Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'detail' of undefined
      self.postCall = {functionName: self.openWindow, params: {mode: "edit", id: event.detail.id}};
    }       
  });

});
```

Comment: What is `event`, and why are are you redeclaring another variable with the same name?  Also, what does `checkToLoad` do, and why are you resolving an empty promise?

Comment: `document.addEventListener(EVENT_REVIEWED, function(event) {` should be used to accept in the event on the event handler, for cross browser support.  Not all browsers make the `event` a global variable

Comment: Good tip @taplar event is to accept event on the event handler. checktoLoad is just some async function. There is nothing to return on the 2nd then.